# Making annotations on plotly.js show or disappear on click

Tags: annotations, plotly.js

I'm using plotly.js for creating a 3D surface / ribbon chart and added annotations that show certain values from my plot. To give the viewer the possibilty to not being obstructed by the annotations, I'd like to switch the annotations on and off or to a lower opacity when clicked. (all of them at the same time).

This is how I create the annotations for each trace:

```
let annotation = {
                x: column,
                y: i+0.25,
                z: row[column],
                xref: 'x',
                yref: 'y',
                zref: 'z',
                text: dataindex[column]+i+':' + row[column],
                showarrow: true,
                arrowhead: 0,
                opacity: 0.8,
                ax: 0,
                ay: -20,
                az: 0,
                //make the annotations respond to click event:
                captureevents: true,
                clickannotation: true,
                editable: true
            }
            annotations.push(annotation);
```

And here I enter them to layout:

```
let layout = {
        autosize: true,
        hovermode: 'closest',
        displayModeBar: true,
        modebar: {
            orientation: 'v',
        },
        margin: {
            l: 20,
            r: 40,
            b: 40,
            t: 40,
        },
        scene: {
            //to adjust the default view, camera perspective can be set (can be also done relatively with row and column if wanted)
            camera: {
                eye: {x: -3, y: -1, z: 1}
            },
            annotations: annotations}}
```

And in for creating the plot I tried this then:

```
    Plotly.newPlot('gd', {
            'data': traces,
             'layout': layout
        }
     );

    var myPlot = document.getElementById('gd');
    
    myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){

    annotations = self.layout.annotations || [];
    annotations.push(annotation);
    Plotly.relayout('gd',{annotations: annotations})
    debugger
    });
```

When hovering over the annotations, the mouse changes to a hand as if it is clickable, but no action behind it. I guess I'm missing the definition somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The property `clickannotation` does not exist. You should use [`clicktoshow`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/annotations/#layout-annotations-items-annotation-clicktoshow) :

> **clicktoshow** : `false | "onoff" | "onout"`
> Makes this annotation respond to clicks on the plot. If you click a data point that exactly
> matches the `x` and `y` values of this annotation, and it is hidden
> (visible: false), it will appear. In "onoff" mode, you must click the
> same point again to make it disappear, so if you click multiple
> points, you can show multiple annotations. In "onout" mode, a click
> anywhere else in the plot (on another data point or not) will hide this
> annotation.

```js
let annotation = {
  // ...
  // ...
  // make the annotations respond to click event:
  clicktoshow: 'onoff',
  captureevents: true,
}
annotations.push(annotation);
```

This allows the user to show/hide annotations individually.

---

Regarding click events, note that `plotly_click` is fired when the user clicks on a trace and only cares about trace data. In order to hide all annotations at once when one of them is clicked, use `plotly_clickannotation`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to get me one step closer to what I intend, but, when clicking on the annotations now I get an error „cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‚annotations‘)“. Any idea where this might be coming from or how it could be fixed?

Comment: I guess it's due to some code you put in a 'plotly_clickannotation' handler (?) - but it's hard to tell without knowing what you did exactly since you read my post. Are you now using the `clicktoshow: 'onoff'` feature or a 'plotly_clickannotation' event handler ? or both ? If a handler is involved, update your post or ask another question with the relevant code and all the details.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that works without clickannotation and captureevents and all this and seems to be quite performant as well.

annotations is defined as mentioned in my original question with

```
var annotation = {
...
}
annotations.push(annotation);
```

First step then to make them appear and disappear upon click is to define scene as a variable outside of the layout environment with all the necessary settings:

```
let scene = {
...
annotions: annotations,
...
};
```

In the layout environment it is assigned in this way:

```
let layout = {
...
hovermode: false, \\not necessary for this solution
scene:scene
};
```

And after that assigning the div variable:

```
var myDiv= document.getElementById('myDiv');
```

After creating the plot via

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', {
'data': traces,
'layout': layout
});
```

the following is now added for making it appear and disappear upon click:

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', (harald)=>{
    if (scene.annotations.length) {
    scene.annotations=[];
    }
    else {
        scene.annotations=annotations;
    }
    // annotations.push(annotation);
    Plotly.relayout('myDiv',{scene: scene})
    });
```